# Filling values in 1D array

Tags: c, arrays, fill

Code Fragment

```
if (val==1)
 paperR[LIMIT]={100,50,20,10,5,2,1};

else if (val==2)
 paperR[LIMIT]={200,100,50,20,10,5,1};
```

PROBLEM ?

it's like doing 
int ask;

LATER IN CODE 
ask=1;

How to do it with array ?

Comment: Is `paperR` a 1D array or a 2D array? If you're assigning an array to a specific element `paperR[LIMIT]`, it must be 2D.

Comment: Yet another guy from the same class that all start asking questions here at once, instead of asking their prof? Probably your prof meant to search SO for answers, not to ask questions directly yourself.

Comment: The initialization list can not be used in this case.

Comment: (In C) "initialisation" and "assignment" are *not* the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to an array, you can only provide a list of values if you're initializing the array at the point where it's being declared.

If you want to fill in an array, you can use `memcpy` from another array that contains the values you want to use. So you can declare:

```
const int arr100[] = {100,50,20,10,5,2,1};
const int arr200[] = {200,100,50,20,10,5,1};
int paperR[LIMIT];

if (val == 1) {
    memcpy(paperR, arr100, sizeof arr100);
} else if (val == 2) {
    memcpy(paperR, arr200, sizeof arr200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do it by one element after other:

```
if (val==1)
{
    paperR[0] = 100;
    paperR[1] =  50;
    paperR[2] =  20;
    paperR[3] =  10;
    paperR[4] =   5;
    paperR[5] =   2;
    paperR[6] =   1;
}
else if (val==2)
{
    paperR[0] = 200;
    paperR[1] = 100;
    paperR[2] =  50;
    paperR[3] =  20;
    paperR[4] =  10;
    paperR[5] =   5;
    paperR[6] =   1;
}
```